# Jquery plugin for cross browser file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload

I need a free(open source) jquery/javascript plugin for uploading files. I got couple of from google like...

- Blueimp
- Fineuploader

Blueimp seems good but documentation is not proper. Can't able to customize as of my need. In IE( mine is - IE9) also it's not working properly.

Fine Uploder is really good but, that is only free for OPEN SOURCE project.

So, if any body know any other good file plugin plz.. share with me.

Regards

Comment: @RayNicholus Fine uploader is really a nice plugin. I feel it's d best one in web right now. But, we are not heavily using file uploads in our project. So, i don't think, it'll be a right decision to get a paid tool for such work. That's why i'm searching for a free one.

Any way, your team are doing a grt job. All d best from myside.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [File uploader](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader). its works for most of the browser-os combination. it is under GNU GPL 2 or later and GNU LGPL 2 license.

Comment: This seems a good solution. In chrome+mozilla it's working well. But, in IE-9+ it's not working.

Comment: what is the error you are getting with IE9 ?

Comment: Simply nothing is happening after clicking on UPLOAD button & selecting file.

Comment: If you are still having an issue, please show your code.  Uploading definitely works fine in ie7 and up.  Most likely there is an issue in the glue code you wrote.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart ...posting code in comments doesn't work well, so you may need to open up a new thread for this.  However, I'm confident that the issue lies in your glue code and perhaps the issue will be obvious after looking at the javascript console.

Comment: @RayNicholus Hey i just go to their demo page in IE ( http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/ ) & tryed to upload one file. But, after clicking on UPLOAD button & selecting file it didn't happened any thing. Where as in case of Chrome+FF it's showing.. file upload animation with progress bar.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I just noticed that the link provided by Peeyush is nothing more than a very very old version of fine Uploader.  The code at that link has been abandoned for some time.  There are likely lots of problems with it.  Http://fineuploader.com has the up to date version.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Simple Ajax Uploader (I'm the primary maintainer):

https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader

It's cross-browser (tested in IE7+), and it's free, open-source (MIT license). Feel free to use it in commercial projects.

Answer (score 0):

Plupload is open source under GPLv2 License, it allows you to upload files using HTML5, Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

http://www.plupload.com/